# Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean ,mysqli_stmt::store_result and mysqli_stmt::close()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

here is my code... it's about using php mysqli extension

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dee");

if ($db->connect_errno)
{
    die('Unable to connect to database');
}
mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");


$storeid=4;
$categoryid=6; 

$statement_store = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_store WHERE store_id=?');
$statement_store->bind_param('i',$storeid);
$statement_store->execute();

$statement_store->store_result();//---------------(1)

$statement_store->bind_result($store_id,$store_name,$store_description,$store_image,$store_open,$store_close,$store_foldername);
$statement_store->fetch();
$store = $store_name;

//$statement_store->close();//--------------(2)


$statement_category = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE category_id=?');
$statement_category->bind_param('i',$categoryid);
$statement_category->execute();
$statement_category->bind_result($category_id,$category_name);
$statement_category->fetch();
$category = $category_name;

echo $store;
echo '<br>';
echo $category;

?>
```

1. Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean error gives
   when not using both (1) and (2)
2. when use (1) or (2) not gives error
3. when use both (1) and (2) not gives error

can anybody tell me what was happen here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't use `store_result()` or `close()` then your first prepared statement (or the result of it) is still "active". This means you must read the data somehow before you can issue a new prepared statement. Because of that your second `prepare()` statement will fail, it returns the boolean value `false`.

Check the `$db->error` field and you will see you get the "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error message. From the MySQL manual [B.5.2.14 Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html):

> If you get `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using `mysql_use_result()` and try to execute a new query before you have called `mysql_free_result()`. It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data without calling `mysql_use_result()` or `mysql_store_result()` in between.